# update_attributes changes attributes even if validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, transactions, update-attributes

For example, if I run `test.update_attributes prop1: 'test', prop2: 'test2'` when `prop1` and `prop2` have validations that prevent those values, `test.prop1` will still be `'test'` and `test.prop2` will still be `'test2'`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Rails docs for `update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes), it's an alias of [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update). Its source is as follows:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb, line 247
def update(attributes)
  # The following transaction covers any possible database side-effects of the
  # attributes assignment. For example, setting the IDs of a child collection.
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    assign_attributes(attributes)
    save
  end
end
```

So, it's wrapped in a DB transaction which is why the rollback happens. However, let's check out `assign_attributes`. According to [its source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 23
def assign_attributes(new_attributes)
  ...
  _assign_attribute(k, v)
  ...
end
```

That [is defined as](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/_assign_attribute):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 53
def _assign_attribute(k, v)
  public_send("#{k}=", v)
rescue NoMethodError
  if respond_to?("#{k}=")
    raise
  else
    raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k)
  end
end
```

So, when you call `test.update_attributes prop1: 'test', prop2: 'test'`, it basically boils down to:

```
test.prop1 = 'test'
test.prop2 = 'test'
test.save
```

If `save` fails the validations, our in-memory copy of `test` still has the modified `prop1` and `prop2` values. Hence, we need to use `test.reload` and the issue is resolved (i.e. our DB and in-memory versions are both unchanged).

**tl;dr** Use `test.reload` after the failed `update_attributes` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in an if-statement:

```
if test.update(test_params)
  # your code here
else
  # your code here  
end
```

Comment: When I try this, `test` still has the same problems after the `if` statement.

Comment: `if` statements aren't always possible; for example, `test.update!` would still cause the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed. For example the `update` controller method usually looks like this:

```
def update
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])

  if @test.update(test_attributes)
    # redirect to index with success messsage
  else
    render :edit
  end

  private

  def test_attributes
    # params.require here
  end
end
```

The `render :edit` will then re-display the form with an error message and the incorrect values filled in for the user to correct. So you actually do want the incorrect values to be available in the model instance.